# Docker runs on getting started dashboard but not on PS Terminal (or any other)

Tags: image, docker, terminal, containers

When I first install docker I can choose to go to the Quick Start Guide interactive window (or once done the quick start guide I can also go there again by right clicking on docker icon and selecting Quick Start Guide on the menu). As you can see I can do anything docker in this windows/environment as shown:
[image: Dockekr works just fine on quick start guide]

as you can see I can pull containers, run containers right there on that quick start guide command line, however, when I open a terminal (be it PS or Git or normal windows CMD) I can't seem to run docker there as shown:
[image]

So not so sure what am I missing. Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at least to my situation, problem is that there was this environment variable DOCKER_HOST (left over from Docker Tools) that was being set, which is not set when I do the quick start guide. Solution was to remove this environment variable from system/user settings and voila I could run docker on the terminal.
[image]